# Can DotNetNuke use another database with existing tables for ASP.NET default membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke, sqlmembershipprovider

We have a case where a web site already exists and is using ASP.NET default membership provider storing Users' data on a SQL Server database.
I need to add a new DotNetNuke site that can share the same membership tables with the existing site.

Is there a way to do this cleanly where the Membership tables remain in the existing database and the rest of the DotNetNuke tables remain in the DNN database?

In other words, must the Membership tables remain in the same database with the rest of the DotNetNuke tables or they can be separated?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create the new DNN site in the existing database? You'd need to do something to ensure it didn't mess with your existing membership tables but you can use the objectqualifier to ensure it doesn't interfere with other existing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible by default, but you can extend the provider to do so. This link can help:

http://www.engagesoftware.com/Support/Forums/forumid/4/threadid/3/scope/posts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Standard (vs. Express) you could use SQL replication to keep the two sets of tables in synch.  Does the user information need to be editable on both sites or can you guarantee that all changes for users would be done on a single database?  If it is just one way, you could probably create a SQL job that copies the data.  I'm also thinking there is a way to do this with views, again only if you can verify that user changes would only be done from one of the two sites.